# emacsclient spending a lot of time resetting faces

Tags: faces, emacsclient, performance

When I launch emacsclient or make a new frame it spends ~2s in:

```
   - make-frame                                                   312  42%
    - frame-creation-function                                     311  42%
     - apply                                                      311  42%
      - #<compiled 0x3edba9>                                      311  42%
       - x-create-frame-with-faces                                311  42%
        - face-set-after-frame-default                            287  39%
         + face-spec-recalc                                       274  37%
```

I have 523 faces in `frame-face-alist` which explains why it's slow. But they all seem to be from packages I use regularly so I can't just get rid off them.

If I replace `face-spec-recalc` with an empty function, the new frame loads instantly so I'm pretty sure that's the culprit.

Is there anything I can do to make new frames load faster?

Maybe load faces lazily or cache them somewhere?

I'd be fine with a hack that meant that I had to restart emacs to pick up new faces.

Comment: I do not know whether you would be interested in buffer-local faces, but I remember launching a thread seeking assistance where I was setting faces and discovered a tremendous overhead / time-suck, and the solution was to use the `face-remapping-alist` which is designed to work quickly during the redisplay process.  It may be worth exploring ... there is a function that uses the `face-remapping-alist`, which is called `face-remap-add-relative`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

Comment: ... continued ... I ended up setting the `face-remapping-alist` as a default for all buffers, and as a buffer-local for other buffers; i.e., `setq-default` and `setq-local`.  Although the docs say to use the `face-remap-add-relative` to do the adjustments, I chose to set the `face-remapping-alist` directly using those default / local approaches.  I primarily use this for certain mode-line custom settings; and, I also use it for how the interactive mini-buffer colorizes the prompt and text when focus is inside or out of the mini-buffer....

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  I remember suffering from very slow frame creation many years ago with similar symptoms, but what you describe is not normal and should get a proper fix.

Comment: I reported a bug and it was merged as a dupe of https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=41200. Looks like there is a patch that improves performance. Hopefully it will land it emacs 27.